# Bash: Read lines in a file scenario with sed or awk

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04, shell, sed, awk

I have this scenarios:

File Content:

```
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
10.1.1.4
```

I want sed or awk so that when i cat the file every time new line is returned.

like

First iteration:

```
cat ip | some magic
10.1.1.1

Second iteration returns
10.1.1.2
Third iteration returns
 10.1.1.3
Fourth iteration returns
10.1.1.4
```

and after n number of iterations, it returns to line 1

Fifth iteration returns:

```
10.1.1.1
```

Can we do it using sed or awk.

Comment: Is there a reason you have specified `sed` or `awk` or would solutions in another language be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the line number in a file and increment it with modulus at each invocation.

```
get_line () {
    if [[ ! -e /var/local/get_line.next ]]
    then
        if [[ ! -e /var/local ]]
        then
            mkdir -p /var/local
        fi
        line_no=1
    else
        line_no=$(< /var/local/get_line.next)
    fi
    file_length=(wc -l < ip_file)
    if ((file_length == 0))
    then
        echo "Error: Data file is empty" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    if ((line > file_length))
    then
        line=1
    fi
    sed -n "$line_no{p;q}" ip_file
    echo "$((++line_no))" > /var/local/get_line.next
}
```

This is in the form of a function which you can incorporate in a script. Feel free to change the location of the get_line.next file. Note that permissions will need to be correct to read or write the files or to create the directory, if necessary.

You will not need to use `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with cat. You also can't seek on a pipe so you can't use a pipe ..

You can do this with a nested while loop

```
while ((1))
do
    while read line
    do
       echo "$line"
    done <somefile
done
```

Comment: That outputs the file in an infinite loop and is the equivalent of the shorter `while ((1)); do cat somefile; done`. Note that `while ((1))` can also be written `while true` or `while :`. You should almost always use `-r` with `read`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson as ever an education. `While((1)); do cat somefile; done` isn't quite the same as echo $file can be replaced with do_something_useful and this meets the OPs requirement 'after n iterations it returns to line 1'.